# email and other notification ringtones get cut off short on my Lumia 928

Tags: ringtone

Why, all of a sudden, do my notification ringtones get cut off short on my Windows phone? I have a 19 second ringtone for my email alerts and now it only plays about 4 or 5 seconds of it. I have used this ringtone for quite a while and now it isn't playing correctly. I have a Nokia Lumia 928.

Comment: How did you set the ringtone? By adding it from your PC?

Comment: Okay. Email tones are affected. How about ringtones for calls? Are they affected too? Also which OS are you running?